# Angular 2 - Inject provider in class (typescript)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Not sure what is the best option but here it goes.

I have the following class

```
export class Order {
    number?: any;
    api?: ApiRequest;
    constructor(number, api: ApiRequest) {
      this.number = number;
      this.api = api;
    }
}
```

When i create the order i use the following

```
let order new Order(123, this.request);
```

ApiRequest is an injectable global provider.

Is there a way i can automatically inject the api provider in the class when i create a new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Injecting only works for instances that are created by DI, not if you create one yourself with `new Xxx()`.

Comment: So what i am using is the only option i have?

Comment: Exactly, if you create an instance with `new Xxx()` you have everything to pass in yourself. You could pass an `Injector` and acquire concrete dependencies withing `Order` like `constructor(injector:Injector) { this.api = injector.get(ApiRequest); }`. I don't know if this is an improvement in your situation.

Comment: Probably it is if i have multiple dependencies. Thanks.